# How to model physics in Blender?

Tags: modeling, physics

I'm robotic engineer. I'm using OpenSCAD to model robotic components (gears, pulleys, parts, etc). But I need application to model physics and interaction of the components (for i.e. how will robot move if I will rotate current gear).

So, is it possible to import OpenSCAD models into Blender and model interactions in it?

I have models in STL format (for i.e. gears). I need to make reductor from it and see how it moves (if possible - measure rotation speed and torque).

Comment: Are you talking about constraints and armatures? Or just the physics simulations?

Comment: I have models in STL format (for i.e. gears). I need to make reductor from it and see how it moves (if possible - measure rotation speed and torque)

Comment: @Robotex As folks are asking for clarifications, try to roll that information back into your question. That way folks are better able to help you with the information you need specifically. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Blender supports some physics simulation for rigid bodies, soft bodies, cloth and fluids. However these are not aimed at CAD applications, there are no tools to measure things like rotation speed and torque, and there is no guarantee that the simulation results will match the real world to some precision.

I think you need to use specialised CAD/CAM software for this.

Answer (score 5):

For those interested in robotics, here are some points of reference.

[Blender wiki - Blender for robotics](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Community%3aScience/Robotics)

[MORSE](https://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse) - a part of the openrobotics project, uses blender as a robotic simulator.

[Warp1337.com](http://www.warp1337.com/content/blender-robotics-part-1-introduction-and-modelling) - a tutorial on modeling and rigging a mechanical arm, ends with info on using a kinect to control the arm in the game engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure stuff if you code it in Python. As for making things move, you will probably have to rig your model. Bones, parents and alike.